# How to automatically resize ribbon controls in VSTO?

Tags: c#, vsto, ribbon

In Office 2007 boxes on the ribbon change their size when window size changes. Here is an example, *Styles* group box on excel *Home* ribbon.

When window is stretched horizontally, *Styles* look like this:

[Fully expanded ribbon group box http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/9652/excelribbonstyleexpande.png](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/9652/excelribbonstyleexpande.png)

If we reduce window width a little, *Styles* will change to this:

[Partially shrunk ribbon group box http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/8297/excelribbonstylesemishr.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/8297/excelribbonstylesemishr.png)

If width is reduced even further, we'll see this:

[Fully shrunk ribbon group box http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/5743/excelribbonstyleshrunk.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/5743/excelribbonstyleshrunk.png)

The question is how to do this with VSTO for custom ribbon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2007 does not support autoscaling of custom groups. It will be in 2010.

[Auto-Scaling of Custom Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691834%28office.14%29.aspx#odc_office2010_TabActivationAutoScaling_AutoScalingCustomControls)

Comment: And how can I take advantage of this autoScale="true" XML-Property when I don't use RibbonXML in my VSTO solution. I have used the Ribbon (Visual Designer). Jörg